# Reading file into C++ an "array" object (not an array)

Tags: c++, arrays

There is a C++ library, in which a function expects an `array` object.

```
    void update(const std::array<T, AN>& input)
```

Its usage example just shows a hypothetical `fill_buffer()`, not an actual code to read file.

```
std::array<unsigned char, 512> buffer;

while (fill_buffer(buffer))
{
    hash_stream.update(buffer);
}
```

I think `ifstream` is the standard C++ way to read file, but `ifstream::read()` takes an actual array, not an `array` object. So, how to solve this problem? Methods I thought of are:

1. Read the file data into an actual array, and then copy the array to the `array` object?
2. Use some other class than `ifstream` to read the file?

What is the recommended way?

Comment: Hint:  The elements of an `std::array` are contiguous, and (for arrays with size `1` or more) the `.data()` member returns a pointer to the first element.

Comment: _ifstream::read() takes an actual array_ Do you mean this [ifstream::read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)? If so, why not `in.read((char*)buffer.data(), buffer.size() * sizeof *buffer.data()));`?

Comment: Beware, the recommendation above will only work if `T` is a POD type.

Comment: There is one problem; how can I set the length? I mean, if I created an `array` object whose length is 512 as the sample code above, and I modify it using the pointer I got from the `data()` method, the length of the actually read bytes could be smaller than 512, I need to tell it that the actual data is not 512.

Comment: The exposed `void update(const std::array<T, AN>& input)` let me think the size of that `std::array` is known beforehand. Otherwise, how will you know the actual size for the call in `update()`? Concerning when `read()` provided less than array size: [SO: C++ Detect if input doesn't satisfy conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357383/7478597)

Comment: @DamnVegetables Then `fill_buffer` needs to tell you how much it filled.

Comment: @Scheff That method seems to be defined as a template, so I guess that the complier creates the `update()` method with the specific length of `array` class, and the `update()` method gets the length using the template variable. Anyway, I think the method is probably not for reading a file in a loop. After examining the source code, I found an overloaded method that takes `void*` and length. There are many overloaded methods like vector<T> or ContiguousIterator, etc  so I had failed to notice that one before asking this question. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the address of the first element.

```
std::array<unsigned char, 512> buffer;
std::ifstream data("File");

// Note: You need the reinterpret_cast here.
//       Even if you don't I would use it to make the code
//       stand out.
while( data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), 512) )
{
}
```

Answer (score -2):

well, I've checked this like this.

1. Generated 512b file with random integers
   `dd if=/dev/random of=512.bin bs=4 count=128 iflag=fullblock`
2. Written this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t int_size = sizeof(int32_t);

    std::array< char, 512 > buffer;
    std::ifstream f("512.bin");
    f.read(buffer.data(), 512);
    f.close();

    union{
        int32_t ret;
        char conv[int_size];
    } conv;

    for(int i =0; i <512; i+=int_size)
    {
        std::memcpy( conv.conv, &(buffer[i]), int_size);
        std::cout << i << " - " << i+int_size << " = " << conv.ret << std::endl;
    }
}
```

3. After run I got this result like this:

```
0 - 4 = 544950647
4 - 8 = -2064427695
8 - 12 = 1451754975
12 - 16 = 1292626444
16 - 20 = -1100810537
20 - 24 = -1835802020
24 - 28 = -5945583
```

So in my opinion, just use `std::array::data()` methode, to get raw pointer on encapsulated data